# Passing parameter between two function/view

Tags: codeigniter

I have two functions in controller named step1 and step2. I want to pass $data array between theme. Below is controller code. In step1 i have input in step2 i have simple echo which shows value of $data['text1']. This value is allays NULL in step2 controller, no meter what I type in step1.

```
    public $data = array(
        'id' => '',
        'text1' => '',
        'text2' => ''
    );

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function step1()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('text1', 'Text 1', 'rquired');
        if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('test/step1', $this->data);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->data['text1'] = $this->input->post('text1');
            redirect('test/step2');
        }
    }

    public function step2()
    {
        $this->load->view('test/step2', $this->data);

    }

    public function step3()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're redirecting to step2 by *redirect('test/step2');* That basically reloads the page and your $data property gets emptied.

Instead, you should try something like that:

```
$this->data['text1'] = $this->input->post('text1');
$this->step2(); //would call your existing step2() method
```

If you actually want to have a header redirect to url like test/step2 , you may need to have your $data stored in a session.